# SharePoint file online open as read only issue

Tags: sharepoint, onedrive, readonly

I had facing some issue with my SharePoint excel online. Recently, my excel file became read only and I cant edit the file in browser version but I can edit it when I open it with desktop app. May I know the solution to solve it so that I can edit the file online.

here an example show as image:
[image: File in read-only]

i had tried others file (excel and word) but seems in onedrive and sharepoint, all fiel open as read only and i cant edit.

Comment: this question is better asked at https://superuser.com or https://stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Please check following tips:

1.Check if you have permissions for theses files.

2.Check whether files are checked-out by another user.

3.Clear browser cache then try to open files again.

4.If you have OneDrive sync running in your PC, try to disable sync and check whether the issue is resolved.

5.Go to site collection features to deactivate  "Limited-access user permission lockdown mode" feature.